# Android OpenCV shared library build error

Tags: android, opencv, makefile, shared-libraries

When I build as static library, the source code builds well in Android JellyBean 4.1.2 using the `mm command`. But when I try to build the opencv folder under `android/external/opencv` as **static library**, with the following changes in `android/external/opencv/Android.mk`

```
+ LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES+= libdl
```

and

```
- include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
+ include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

- LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcxcore libcv libcvaux libcvml libcvhighgui
+ LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcxcore libcv libcvaux libcvml libcvhighgui
```

I get the following error:

```
android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: internal error in thumb_branch_common, at /tmp/android-8532/src/build/../binutils/binutils-2.21/gold/arm.cc:4148
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/mydevice/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcxcore_intermediates/LINKED/libcxcore.so] Error 1
```

Any idea on how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Jai

Answer (score 2):

> ,,, arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: internal error in thumb_branch_common, 
>   at /tmp/android-8532/src/build/../binutils/binutils-2.21/gold/arm.cc:4148
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Any idea on how to fix this error?

In Binutils, file arm.cc, Line 4148 there was an Internal Error (in Binutils).

Try newer Binutils (or older) or fix the Bug and submit the Patch.

You can also switch to a different Toolchain (using a different Binutils) and
try that. Sometimes Compiler switches will alter the operation enough to avoid
the Bug.

There is a CHANCE that simply altering the order of the Function in the Source File 
of the Code you are compiling (NOT gold/arm.cc, that is where the Compiler Bug is, 
change YOUR Source) and that Binutils will read the newly ordered Code differently
and thus avoid the Binutils Bug.

It is also possible that the Code you are linking (the .o Files) was corrupted
either on Disk or by a Bug in the Compiler, or that it is for the wrong endian
(etc.) and that is not being detected.

PS: Thumb-2 Code (in the Compiler's Toolchain) is not Bug free (as you noticed).

See here for some People working on a fix:
http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core-contrib/commit/?h=kraj/gold&id=b72f3238ad32ab420306a0226d8c2e57c52ddf45

... and this is what they came up with:
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=6284&action=diff